# One script to click buttons on two different pages?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I manage a site that has multiple embedded web pages. It is a form of Mantis Bug Tracker that is used to submit tickets. Once a ticket is created it is given a few buttons, Close, assign etc. I am looking to Select the close button, which I can already do then click in the closing notes area which I was able to determine based off of knowing the elements and using `document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Close]")[0].click()`.

This works. However it's done using two scripts.

I am trying to condense it into one script.

I have tried adding an include of the second page and the script desired for the specific page, however in the real world that doesn't quite work.

Script 1:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 117) {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Close]")[0].click();
    } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 66) {
        alert("Ctrl + B shortcut combination was pressed");
    } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which == 89) {
        alert("Ctrl + Alt + Y shortcut combination was pressed");
    }
}
```

Script 2:

```
var EffectiveDate = "";
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 117) {
        document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name=bugnote_text]")[0].value = " ";
        document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Close Ticket']")[0].click();

    } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 66) {
        alert("Ctrl + B shortcut combination was pressed");
    } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which == 89) {
        alert("Ctrl + Alt + Y shortcut combination was pressed");
    }
}
```

The first group of code is designed for the first initial page where it just needs to find a specific button and press it. Once it is processed. I would like to have the second group of code to seamlessly run after the new page is loaded but as of right now these are two separate scripts that are successful in doing what I desire.

I am able to find the elements desired and can correctly do the process stated just looking to simplify the script into one script.  This of course does not run as it has been given but it does work in separate userscripts. Is this Possible?

Comment: Have you tried stripping the shared logic into one JavaScript file that is imported into the two pages?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I mean I have tried having both pages matched and have the code for both tasks in the same file but I am so new in JavaScript I am sure I am messing something up in the process. With my understanding each task would need its own function correct? So the initial closing would need its own function and the secondary closing would need its own function right? But if that was the case would it toss an error when running? In the settings for the Userscript file I  have it to match both web pages being used. But then again I am pretty lost and can do basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the script to do the **same thing** on 2 different pages, merely adjust the `@match` and/or `@include` directives to fire on both pages.
2. To get one script to do **different things** on 2 different pages:
   A) Make sure it fires on both pages per step 1.
   B) Test `location` properties to determine which code to fire.

For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Click on two pages
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/PATH_FOO/*
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/PATH_BAR/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener ("keydown", zEvent => {
    if (zEvent.which == 117) {  //  F6
        zEvent.preventDefault();
        if (location.pathname.includes("/PATH_FOO/") ) {
            document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Close]")[0].click();
        }
        else if (location.pathname.includes("/PATH_BAR/") ) {
            document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name=bugnote_text]")[0].value = " ";
            document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Close Ticket']")[0].click();
        }
    }
    else if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.which == 66) {
        zEvent.preventDefault();
        alert("Ctrl + B shortcut combination was pressed");
    }
    else if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.altKey && zEvent.which == 89) {
        zEvent.preventDefault();
        alert("Ctrl + Alt + Y shortcut combination was pressed");
    }
} );
```

---

Some of the other issues with the question code:

1. It uses already defined browser hotkeys (vary by browser and OS). So use `.preventDefault()` to avoid side affects and extra actions.
2. Likewise, firing on `keyup` will fire too late to prevent default actions (which mostly fire on `keydown`).
3. Don't use `.on...` event handlers, use `addEventListener`.
4. Debugging by `alert()` is annoying and problematic (it masks some problems and can cause others).  Use `console.log`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get it up and running for what I needed. Now i Just have to add all the extra stuff left but for now this got me in the right direction. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) for that. It has libs for many different languages and since it is a tool especially for test automation, it might help you out there.

You could also try [Selenium IDE](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/getting-started/) and record your workflow, to replay it later on when needed.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I am not sure how this resolves any issue as my issue isn't a testing issue because I have no issue testing what I am doing. Its just a matter of figuring out what exactly I am not doing to get this userscript to take both processes. A simple IDE wont matter as I will be in the same situation trying to figure out how to get this to work as intended.

Comment: You provide very little information about your core problem though. If you control both sites you may interact between them as you like (but that requires most likely changes on both sites). If you have 2 existing sites and just want to automate some workflow I can again just recommend Selenium for that. Even if you don't use it for testing! You may use it to automatically buy things on amazon if you like. Sorry if that doesn't solve your problem, but you would need to be more specific in order to get proper help!

Comment: I thought I was pretty specific but I apologize. I manage one whole site. This site has multiple embedded web pages ie. one button takes you to a specific web page. The site I use is a form of Mantis Bug Tracker that is used to submit tickets. Once a ticket is created it is given a few buttons, Close, assign etc. I am looking to Select  the close button, which I can already do then click in the closing notes area which I was able to determine based off of knowing the elements and using a document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Close]")[0].click(). This works. However its done using two scripts.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the amount of scripts needed to automate ticket closure and message then click a completely different button called close ticket which is on an embedded webpage for the same site.  I can get both processes to work via separate scripts and my main if you want it to be called a problem is just wanting it to all be condensed into one script.

Comment: I currently have no solution for this then. You might want to update your question, with the additional information you just posted. It could be helpful for others providing you with the right answer without scrolling thru the comments.